# Typical minimum silkscreen-pad spacing

Tags: pcb, pad, silkscreen

What is a typical industry figure for the minimum spacing between silkscreen and pads? When I look at a manufacturer's general list of capabilities, sometimes this number isn't even listed. I haven't chosen a fab house yet so I'm looking for a general value.

Comment: Most proto-houses, at least, will automatically trim your gerbers so you don't get silkscreen on the pads.

Comment: Agreed. Silkscreen won't be printed over copper or non-tented holes.

Comment: Yeah, but if they trim it, will the silkscreen be pushed back, or removed altogether? (the answer probably depends on the board house haha) I'd rather have an idea of how much space to leave, so I don't have to leave it up to them at all.

Answer (score 1):

As a general value Silkscreen will be clipped  back from any corresponding soldermask pad to a diameter of 0,1 mm in order to prevent pads being printed on.

Answer (score 1):

I've never known a PCB manufacturer to move the silk screen, only ever to not print the specific part that would be printed on exposed copper.

If you want less generalised information from a specific manufacturer then all the ones I've interacted with in the past have always been very friendly and helpful either over email or telephone call.

Answer (score 1):

Most fabrication shops will automatically trim the silkscreen against solder mask openings. But keep in mind that most fabrication shops will increase the solder mask openings as well, because solder mask to copper registration is never perfect.

But as a general value my recommendation is to keep a minimum gap of 0.2 mm between silkscreen and copper features. This should be plenty for 99% of all PCB shops. So you won't lose information on the silkscreen (reference designators, pin 1 indicators, ...) even if the PCB shop has to increase solder mask openings.

Answer (score 0):

I'd just ask the PCB manufacturer what they recommend. But really it's up to you. I've seen boards come back from a manufacturer and you can practically blow on the small silkscreen fingers (1-2mil width) and they would come off the board. This can be a problem for the assembler so it's a good idea to keep them as wide as possible and if they are too thin, then remove them entirely.